# C# - INSERTING new row in database table using DATASETS fails?

Tags: c#, insert, dataset

I have a database containing one table with several columns, first of which is the auto generated ID.

I've created a dataset (.xsd) from it, and I'm trying to use it for reading, writing into and updating the database.

So far, **reading** works fine, all I have to do is:

```
var reservations = new DataSet1.reservationsDataTable();
var ta = new DataSet1TableAdapters.reservationsTableAdapter();
ta.Fill(reservations);

for (int i = 0; i < reservations.Rows.Count; i++)
{
// read whatever I need here...
}
```

However, when I try updating my database with these lines, **it fails** and it doesn't create a new record in my database:

```
var ta = new DataSet1TableAdapters.reservationsTableAdapter();
ta.Insert(LastName,Arrival,Departure);
```

Of course, I previously initialize variables LastName, Arrival and Departure with the user input. I also tried creating a new Insert query, but same thing happens, even worse - it wants a *string* type of input for a DateTime (Arrival, Departure).

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

P.S - I also need to *UPDATE* my database using datasets later, so I really need to figure this out.

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I don't get any errors really, it just doesn't write anything into the database.

Comment: Have you set types of columns in your dataset to DateTime? Also, check what id is generated? Maybe it is generating -1 or something, and you don't see it in the database.

Comment: And of cource, make sure your dataset column types match with database column types.

Comment: The column types match in both my database datatable and dataset table (it was auto generated after all), but I don't know any way of checking what ID it generated because I can't find the record of storing it anywhere... it's like it didn't do anything at all

Comment: Check your AutoIncrementSeed and AutoInrementStep. First is starting number, second is increment value. Set AutoIncrementSeed to some value higher than the highest in your database table. This is btw. bad practice. You should inrement your id in the before insert trigger in the database.

Comment: Both of those values were set to "-1". I tried changing the seed to 100 and putting increment value to 1, but still nothing...

Comment: It appears that I need to somehow "update" my database now that I put new stuff in my dataset - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x.aspx

Comment: i think you should merge your questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428113/c-sharp-updating-dataset-fails and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426574/c-sharp-inserting-new-row-in-database-table-using-datasets-fails into one question and close the other.