# UPDATING Dataset Fails?

Tags: c#, database, dataset

According to this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x.aspx , after I insert/change data in the dataset, I need to call the UPDATE to synchronize my database data with the dataset data.

My problem is this:

I have created a dataset called dataset1.xsd and then I create a new TableAdapter to do my INSERT query with, and THEN I need to somehow let my database know that the stuff in dataset has changed.

```
DataSet1TableAdapters.reservationsTableAdapter ta = new DataSet1TableAdapters.reservationsTableAdapter();

ta.Insert(LastName,Arrival,Departure);  // this is where I do the INSERT query
```

Now I should update the dataset, right? How do I do this? The article I posted above suggests doing something like this:

```
ta.Update(DataSet1.reservationsDataTAble);
```

However, I can't do this because:

*Error - 'myproject.DataSet1.reservationsDataTable' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context.*

I tried declaring a new Dataset1 DataTable, and then updating that, but it still won't show any changes in my database.

I KNOW, however, that the changes are saved in the DataSet, because when I fill a new datatable later, the record is there.

EDIT: Thanks to the comments, below, I tried doing this for a change:

```
DataSet1.reservationsDataTable NDT = new DataSet1.reservationsDataTable();                   

DataSet1TableAdapters.reservationsTableAdapter ta = new DataSet1TableAdapters.reservationsTableAdapter();

ta.Insert(LastName,Arrival,Departure);

ta.Fill(NDT);   
ta.Update(NDT);
```

... and I could see (in the debugger) that the NDT datatable DID in fact contain the data that was "INSERTED" and then filled into the data table.

**However, the `ta.Update(NDT);` still did not update my database...**

Comment: Usually the way to go is that the adapter loads the data into a `DataTable` or `DataSet`. This object is then given to the `Update` method of the adapter. At the moment `DataSet1.reservationsDataTAble` represents the type that holds the data. Instead, use the instance of the type.

Comment: What is DataSet1? is it a property or a type? You need to operate on a created dataset instance and it is not clear from your code if you create one.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions - I added an "EDIT" to the original question, this is what happened...

Comment: You fill NDT and then immediately save it. There are no changed records there at the moment, nothing to save. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms233812(v=vs.80).aspx how to insert a record to a table. You create a new row, insert it and then save a table.

Comment: But how can I create a new row if my "ID" is automatically created for me? I would have to manually insert an ID field for the row then...

Comment: Use a temporary id in your Dataset and replace it with the real one when updating the database. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0.aspx

Comment: i think you should merge your questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428113/c-sharp-updating-dataset-fails and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426574/c-sharp-inserting-new-row-in-database-table-using-datasets-fails into one question and delete the other.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you all - it still doesn't work though, I've tried all the suggestions. I've also went ahead and asked my professor at the university which told me that Visual Studio 2010 creates copies to output directories (of database) by default, so I should turn that off, so I did - and then all hell broke loose, I had to reconfigure my database path, then I couldnt run the app because it said that the database was being used by another process, namely Windows NT SQL Server, etc. HOW CAN THIS BE SO HARD???

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `However, the ta.Update(NDT); still did not update my database` means that no sql-insert is executed and that yo get no exception.

does this work for you?

```
var myDataSet1 = new DataSet1();

var newReservation = myDataSet1.reservations.NewRow();

newReservation.LastName=...
newReservation.Arrival=...
newReservation.Departure=...

myDataSet1.reservations.AddreservationsRow(newReservation);

var ta = new DataSet1TableAdapters.reservationsTableAdapter();

ta.Update(myDataSet1.reservations);
```

Comment: newReservation.LastName=...   (there is no variable LastName in this newly created row), or any other variables, just some default ones

Comment: besides, if I create only a row, I would have to create an ID as well, and my ID is automatically generated in the database, so there has to be a more elegant approach...

Comment: the generated insert-sql from the dbadapter does onmit the dataset-primary-keys. have you tried it?